# regex space validation

Tags: regex

I want to make a javascript function that will prompt user to put space after every 26 characters.Means it will be necessary for user to put space after 26 characters in a textbox which has total length of 58. if user put space before 26 letters then it should count
letters after space

Comment: What have you tried?  Why not just do a check and add it for them if they didn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're planning to do, but if you want to stop people from entering more than 26 non-space characters in a row, then the regex

```
/\S{27}/
```

will check for that. If it matches, the string contains 27 or more non-space characters.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function nospaces(t){
if(t.value.match(/\S{27}/) ){
alert('Sorry, you are not allowed to enter any spaces');
t.value=t.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" maxlength="58" name ="textbox" id="textbox" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">
</body>
</html>

Comment: the problem is that it does not allow to enter any character after 27th.

Comment: You wrote in your question that it should not be possible for the user to enter more characters if there isn't a space after 26 non-spaces. What *do*  you want to happen?

Comment: what i need is a s pace after every 26 letters if a user writes a string more than 26 letter,he should not be allowed

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid you're not making much sense. Please edit your question and describe in detail and clearly what you want to happen under which circumstances.

Comment: @user1514793 When do you want to alert them? Do you want to alert them the moment a word is over 26 chars (onkeyup), or do you want to alert them after they've finished typing (onsubmit)?

Comment: ok let;s make it clear,,,,i have a textbox named contact title,length of 58 characters.obviously user can put a single word of 58 characters which is causing layout issue for me. I want to validate user input that if user puts a word longer than 26 letters he should be prompted to use space

Comment: @wiseguy at  the moment a word is over 26 chars (onkeyup)

Comment: I think bizzar has more that 26 letters.

Comment: +1 for solving his problem. OP, you can mark his answer correct if it solved your problem.